# AngularJS - binding on demand

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I edited my question because I realized that the best solution for me will be to late bind the drop down control to a property on my scope.

I'm using kendo dropdownlist with angular, and facing a problem:

How can I bind the drop down value only after the data source is filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the k-ng-delay attribute on the drop down element?

For example,

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select kendo-drop-down-list 
            k-options="customOptions" 
            k-ng-delay="customOptions.dataSource">
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is a link with more information on k-ng-delay: [AngularJS Introduction](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction)